# Data Loss in an unsafely unplugged External Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-loss

I have a 1Tb External Hard Drive Disk that was accidentally unsafely unplugged while opening some files in a certain directory. When I plugged my device again, all data in that directory was lost. I tried to do `ls -l` in that directory and this happened:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 0
```

I entered `dmesg` and this was the result:

```
[241539.098561] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.098596] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.098609] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.098623] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 60 04 00 00 00 10 00
[241539.098629] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 6292480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[241539.098649] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 786304, lost async page write
[241539.098733] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 786305, lost async page write
[241539.098770] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.098780] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.098790] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.098799] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 63 30 c0 00 00 08 00
[241539.098805] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 6500544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241539.098820] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 812312, lost async page write
[241539.098858] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.098862] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.098865] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.098868] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 64 73 d8 00 00 08 00
[241539.098870] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 6583256 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241539.098876] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 822651, lost async page write
[241539.098919] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.098925] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.098928] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.098932] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 31 c3 6e b0 00 00 08 00
[241539.098934] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 834891440 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241539.098940] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 104361174, lost async page write
[241539.098970] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.098977] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.098984] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.098991] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a fe 3f 88 00 00 08 00
[241539.098995] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 989740936 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241539.099006] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 123717361, lost async page write
[241539.099026] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.099033] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.099041] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.099047] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5a e7 b8 30 00 00 08 00
[241539.099051] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 1525135408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241539.099060] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 190641670, lost async page write
[241539.099079] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[241539.099085] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[241539.099092] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[241539.099098] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 72 7b 35 00 00 00 18 00
[241539.099102] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 1920677120 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[241539.099112] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240084384, lost async page write
[241539.099122] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240084385, lost async page write
[241539.099129] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240084386, lost async page write
[241558.681121] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.685370] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.689602] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.693861] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.698128] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.702382] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241558.797112] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[241558.797319] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797332] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 63 30 c0 00 00 08 00
[241558.797347] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797354] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 64 73 d8 00 00 10 00
[241558.797367] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797371] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 31 c3 6e b0 00 00 08 00
[241558.797376] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797381] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a fe 3f 88 00 00 08 00
[241558.797386] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797390] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5a e7 b8 30 00 00 08 00
[241558.797396] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD 
[241558.797400] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 72 7b b5 00 00 00 18 00
[241558.797443] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797448] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 63 30 c0 00 00 08 00
[241558.797451] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6500544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241558.797460] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 812312, lost async page write
[241558.797490] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797494] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 64 73 d8 00 00 10 00
[241558.797496] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6583256 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[241558.797501] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 822651, lost async page write
[241558.797507] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 822652, lost async page write
[241558.797516] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797519] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 31 c3 6e b0 00 00 08 00
[241558.797522] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 834891440 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241558.797527] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 104361174, lost async page write
[241558.797538] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797542] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#15 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a fe 3f 88 00 00 08 00
[241558.797544] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 989740936 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241558.797549] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 123717361, lost async page write
[241558.797561] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797565] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5a e7 b8 30 00 00 08 00
[241558.797567] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1525135408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[241558.797573] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 190641670, lost async page write
[241558.797584] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[241558.797588] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 72 7b b5 00 00 00 18 00
[241558.797591] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1920709888 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[241558.797597] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240088480, lost async page write
[241558.797603] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240088481, lost async page write
[241558.797609] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 240088482, lost async page write
[241558.797622] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6292480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[241558.797627] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 786304, lost async page write
[241559.121930] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[241559.377352] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[241575.361242] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[241575.515985] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[241575.516001] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[241575.516007] usb 2-1.1: Product: Expansion
[241575.516011] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[241575.516015] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[241575.517492] scsi host3: uas
[241575.519081] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[241575.521697] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[241575.522305] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[241576.545233] ....ready
[241579.619062] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 18446744073709551615 512-byte logical blocks: (9.44 ZB/8.00 ZiB)
[241579.675103] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[241579.675111] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[241579.679301] usb 2-1.1: cmd cmplt err -71
[241579.679309] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[241579.922995] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[241579.923131] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[241579.923137] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#23 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 08 00 04 00
[241579.923179] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[241579.923185] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[241579.923199] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[241579.957325] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[241579.957332] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[241579.957344] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[241579.957346] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[241579.957357] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[241579.957371] sda: detected capacity change from -1 to 0
[241579.957376] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[241595.173194] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[241595.328277] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[241595.328290] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[241595.328296] usb 2-1.1: Product: Expansion
[241595.328301] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[241595.328305] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: NAC3EHNF
[241595.331423] scsi host3: uas
[241595.333162] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[241595.335454] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[241595.337198] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[241595.337205] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[241595.752747] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[241595.752758] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[241595.753478] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[241595.754152] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[241596.397311]  sda: sda1
[241596.416708] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[320784.752943] audit: type=1400 audit(1648383598.970:88): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=1520 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[320786.026971] audit: type=1400 audit(1648383600.242:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=1520 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[320787.088629] audit: type=1326 audit(1648383601.302:90): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=1520 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f30561e13cb code=0x50000
[336335.389031] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 5:1:790f817d, in Isolated Web Co [137497]
[336335.389201] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
[336335.492216] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Isolated Web Co[137497] context reset due to GPU hang
[340162.304941] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 5:1:790f917d, in Isolated Web Co [138822]
[340162.305024] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
[340162.407988] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Isolated Web Co[138822] context reset due to GPU hang
[359282.434242] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[359282.434251] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[359282.434255] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[359282.434259] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6e 42 b5 00 00 00 08 00
[359282.434261] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 1849865472 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[359282.800632] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[359282.800743] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[359282.800782] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[359282.800791] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6e 42 b5 00 00 00 08 00
[359282.800797] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 1849865472 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[359282.800838] buffer_io_error: 7 callbacks suppressed
[359282.800844] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 231232928, async page read
[359283.006852] usb 2-1.1: cmd cmplt err -71
[359283.006868] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[359283.008222] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[359283.008329] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[359283.008335] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6e 42 b5 00 00 00 08 00
[359283.008374] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[359283.008377] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6e 42 b5 00 00 00 08 00
[359283.008379] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1849865472 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[359283.008386] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 231232928, async page read
[359283.475094] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[359283.738738] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[359293.562637] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[359293.717443] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[359293.717452] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[359293.717456] usb 2-1.1: Product: Expansion
[359293.717459] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[359293.717462] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[359293.718509] scsi host3: uas
[359293.721925] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[359293.724083] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[359293.724750] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[359294.750675] ....ready
[359297.824497] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 18446744073709551615 512-byte logical blocks: (9.44 ZB/8.00 ZiB)
[359297.952504] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[359297.952517] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[359297.956512] usb 2-1.1: cmd cmplt err -71
[359297.956531] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[359297.984651] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[359297.984809] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#1 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[359297.984815] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#1 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 08 00 04 00
[359297.984923] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[359297.984932] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[359297.984957] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[359298.034713] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[359298.034721] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[359298.034730] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[359298.034733] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[359298.034743] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[359298.034755] sda: detected capacity change from -1 to 0
[359298.034759] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[359310.194550] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[359310.349040] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[359310.349053] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[359310.349059] usb 2-1.1: Product: Expansion
[359310.349063] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[359310.349067] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: NAC3EHNF
[359310.350549] scsi host3: uas
[359310.352007] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[359310.354515] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[359310.355269] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[359311.390513] ....ready
[359314.463973] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[359314.501682] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[359314.501701] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[359314.502377] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[359314.502875] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[359314.560083]  sda: sda1
[359314.577734] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[359694.579135] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[359694.579150] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 5e f8 00 00 08 00
[359694.579234] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=1s
[359694.579240] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 5e f8 00 00 08 00
[359694.579244] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953521400 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[359694.579374] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953521400 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[359694.579387] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 244189919, async page read
[359694.606209] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[359694.880182] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[359694.937962] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[359718.400040] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[359718.554468] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[359718.554483] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[359718.554489] usb 2-1.1: Product: Expansion
[359718.554494] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[359718.554498] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: NAC3EHNF
[359718.556691] scsi host3: uas
[359718.558089] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[359718.560247] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[359718.561202] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[359719.579976] ....ready
[359722.653700] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[359722.978332] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[359722.978343] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[359722.979066] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[359722.979564] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[359723.202588]  sda: sda1
[359723.261691] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[360216.705602] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=1s
[360216.705615] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[360216.705621] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 Add. Sense: Invalid field in cdb
[360216.705630] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 33 77 5c 40 00 00 08 00
[360216.705633] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 863460416 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360306.554130] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[360306.554143] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[360306.554147] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[360306.554153] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 5f d4 f0 00 00 08 00
[360306.554157] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 6280432 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360306.554168] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 784798, lost async page write
[360306.554198] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[360306.554209] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[360306.554213] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[360306.554216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#19 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 63 30 c0 00 00 08 00
[360306.554218] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 6500544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360306.554225] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 812312, lost async page write
[360306.554259] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[360306.554263] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[360306.554268] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[360306.554271] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 31 c3 6e b0 00 00 08 00
[360306.554273] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 834891440 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360306.554279] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 104361174, lost async page write
[360306.554292] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[360306.554295] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[360306.554299] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[360306.554303] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a fe 3f 98 00 00 08 00
[360306.554305] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 989740952 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360306.554310] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 123717363, lost async page write
[360306.940988] usb 2-1.1: stat urb: status -71
[360307.150741] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[360307.150870] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[360307.150877] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5a f0 37 c0 00 00 08 00
[360307.150924] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[360307.150929] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] tag#17 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 5a f0 37 c0 00 00 08 00
[360307.150932] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1525692352 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360307.150945] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 190711288, lost async page write
[360307.150980] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1525135408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[360307.150990] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 190641670, lost async page write
[360307.267991] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[360307.524316] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[360353.531644] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[360353.686112] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[360353.686127] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[360353.686133] usb 2-1.2: Product: Expansion
[360353.686138] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[360353.686142] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[360353.689896] scsi host3: uas
[360353.691347] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[360353.693597] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[360353.694320] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[360354.711659] ...ready
[360356.761251] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 18446744073709551615 512-byte logical blocks: (9.44 ZB/8.00 ZiB)
[360356.975781] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[360356.975791] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[360356.979815] usb 2-1.2: cmd cmplt err -71
[360356.979835] usb 2-1.2: stat urb: status -71
[360357.016398] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[360357.016600] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#29 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[360357.016610] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#29 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 08 00 04 00
[360357.016704] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[360357.016717] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[360357.016755] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[360357.055899] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[360357.055911] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[360357.055932] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[360357.055937] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[360357.055956] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[360357.055981] sda: detected capacity change from -1 to 0
[360357.055989] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[360374.879318] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[360375.041777] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
[360375.041793] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[360375.041799] usb 2-1.2: Product: Expansion
[360375.041804] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[360375.041808] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: NAC3EHNF
[360375.045732] scsi host3: uas
[360375.047532] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[360375.049873] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[360375.050625] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[360376.055282] ...ready
[360378.104907] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[360378.142809] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[360378.142822] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[360378.143505] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[360378.144142] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[360378.190246]  sda: sda1
[360378.235792] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[360857.015864] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[360857.280624] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[360857.354916] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[360864.532598] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[360864.686774] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2322, bcdDevice= 1.00
```

It displays more information but I cannot post more that 30000 characters

How can I fix my Directory and access the data that was there again?

Comment: To display the full log, I suggest you paste them onto a Pastebin, then send us the link.

Comment: but, is it necessary? can't be solved with the information I posted?

Comment: @Dauph It will help. And while I'm not trying to rub it in, please have redundancy next time and (offsite) backups of anything important, perhaps in the cloud or to a server somewhere else. And while you should also use RAID (or ZFS) for important data, [RAID is not a backup](https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup), so ideally use RAID + a backup. In this case, if you had a tested offsite backup, restoring would have been very easy.

Comment: This is the complete information displayed: https://pastebin.com/L0qjV1FA. You're right, I like having backups too, but I had too much information in this disk and I was not capable at that moment to afford to buy another 1 Tb External Hard Drive Disk. I don't know what is redundancy but I will search for it

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the solution. Redundancy is having multiple copies of data. For example, if I have three copies of file X (on separate disks), and a checksum indicates that one of the three copies is different, then I can get that file back by looking at the two good copies

Comment: I have already solved it, although surprisingly it was using windows. I opened cmd as administrator, typed `chkdsk E: /f` and that was it, my files were recovered. Thanks to everyone, I will be more careful next time, and I will try to implement redundancy on my data

Comment: Did you try fsck under Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, I typed `sudo fsck -a /dev/sda` but it didn't solve it

Comment: Oh, I see. I think next time when we see somebody is corrupting their NTFS, they should go to Windows first...